# lexical scoping in scheme

Tags: scheme, programming-languages, lexical-scope

I am trying to understand concepts of lexical and dynamic scoping and the differences between them.
Let's take a look at the following code:

```
(let ((a 1)
      (b 2))
  (letrec ((f (lambda () F))
            (g (lambda (c) G)))
    (lambda (d)
      (+ (f) (g b)))))
```

For expressions F and G, which variables are at lexical scope of `(lambda(d)...)`?

Comment: That code would have the same meaning with both scoping mechanisms, so it's very difficult to tell the difference between them from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(lambda(d)...)` has `d` as bound variable and `f`, `g` `a` `b` and all of the global scope as free variables.

**EDIT**

Just to demonstrate the code in Scheme and some other language where the same bindings are dynamic. Since neither of your functions call each other you might as well keep them in the same `let`:

```
(define test
  (let ((a 1)
        (b 2)
        (f (lambda () F))
        (g (lambda (c) G)))
    (lambda (d)
      (+ (f) (g b)))))

;; for the test we need the F and G defined
(define F 10)
(define G 20)

(test 4) ; ==> 30 (aka (+ F G))
```

What happens is that when the `lambda` gets evaluated the variables it uses from the lexical scope lives on even after the `let` is gone. In a dymaic scope this isn't true:

```
(test 4)
; ERROR f: unbound identifier
```

The reason for this is while `a`, `b`, `f` and `g` existed when the lamba was evaluated none of the variables get captured like in lexical scope and thus when the procedure `test` is made none of the local variables exist anymore. In fact you might as well write it like this:

```
;; in a dynamic lisp this s the same 
(define test
  (lambda (d)
    (+ (f) (g b))))
```

And you must make sure the variable exist when you call the function (aka dynamic)

```
(define g (lambda (v) 1337))
(define f (lambda () 3.1415927))
(define b 13)
(test 4) ; ==> 1340.1415927
```

Now if you were to add the above definitions in the global scope and keep the original definition you'd still get `30` since a lexical lisp uses the closer lexical bindings rather than the global ones.

Another great example is this:

```
(define x 10)
(define (test v)
  (+ x v))

(let ((x 20))
  (test 10))
; ==> ?
```

In a lexical lisp the result would be always `20` since `test` does not have any idea of the `let` since it is not in its lexical scope. It's `x` is always the global bindings `x`. In a dymamic lisp the `x` from the `let` is the closest one from the runtime point of view which would result in `30` since the `x` in `test` is the *same* as the `x` in the `let` and it shadows the global `x`.

Comment: Thanks, why f and g?

Comment: `f` and `g` are variables just like `+` and `b` and you can see thet they are created before evaluating `(lambda (d) ...)`. I've added a little more about how error prone code is under dynamic scope.